# Call to sybase stored procedure doesn't always return correct number of rows when using the data

Tags: c#, odbc, sybase

I'm having a simple application where I am calling a stored procedure in Sybase using a OdbcConnection. I think this is working really inconsistent and I can't tell why.

After calling the stored procedure I put it in a List> and then make the result into a xml and save it on disc.

When running my application and calling the same stored procedure I get different results every once and while. The stored procedure is very simple and should always return 1800 rows.

SP:

```
SELECT   Column1
        ,Column2
FROM database..Table
```

Call to database:

```
public List<Dictionary<String, Object>> GetDataFromDB(string DbConnection, string sp)
{
        var result = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
        using (var con = new OdbcConnection(DbConnection))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = sp;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 15;
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                result = GetDataFromQuery(reader);
            }
        }
        return result;
}

private List<Dictionary<String, Object>> GetDataFromQuery(IDataReader reader)
{
        var cols = new String[reader.FieldCount];
        for (var ordinal = 0; ordinal < reader.FieldCount; ordinal++)
            cols[ordinal] = reader.GetName(ordinal);

        var retList = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

        while (reader.Read())
            retList.Add(cols.ToDictionary(t => t, t => reader[t]));

        return retList;
 }
```

And finally my to XML method:

```
public XDocument ToXML(string collectionName, IEnumerable<Dictionary<String, Object>> data)
{
        xml = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Table",
                new XAttribute("name", collectionName),
                    from x in data
                        select new XElement("row", x.Select(y => new XAttribute(y.Key, y.Value)))));
}
```

To save the XML I use .Save(path).

So, the GetDataFromDB does not return all the rows that it should, all the time. It's working mostly, but maybe 1 out of 5 is wrong. I've tried to put the reader into a datatable and then count the rows, and it's always 1800. But somewhere rows are getting lost, my guess is that GetDataFromQuery... Sometimes the XML contains 300 rows, and sometimes 1800.

[image: XML sizes]

Can someone help me to see where the problem is?